# iPhone - Phonegap UI Controls - Tab Bar

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios4, jqtouch, cordova

Just started with Sencha today and found it a bit overwhelming.  Was able to get a nice custom tabbar working, and top nav panel, however am stuck from where to go.

Decided it might be a lot easier to just use JQTouch and a Phonegap TabBar instead.  I found: [http://phonegap.pbworks.com/iPhone%3A-UIControls-(TabBar)](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/iPhone%3A-UIControls-%28TabBar%29)

I'm on the latest 0.91 version of Phonegap, and the example given on that page doesn't seem to work...  http: //skitch.com/nelga/d4nfd/iphone-simulator

Does anyone have a suggestion for the best method of integrating a custom iPhone Tabbar using PhoneGap and JQTouch?

Thanks,
Glen

Comment: might need some additional information if you want an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is slightly confusing, as you mentioned you worked with Sencha as well. This answer is about adding a tab bar with jQTouch.

To include a tab bar in jQTouch, you'll need to download a later version of jQT than r109. Go to [its GitHub](http://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch) to grab the latest version (currently r148).

Then refer to [an answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783248/fixed-header-in-jqtouch/3394044#3394044) previously.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry. I started developing with Sencha, but found it over my head.  I moved into jqTouch which has been great.  Is that link the most current way to get a stable tabbar in an iPhone app using jqTouch & PhoneGap?  I'd also seen iScroll - but unfortunately it is said to not work well with forms.

Comment: I haven't developed for PhoneGap myself, but for a pure web app, yes. Another approach you may consider is hybrid: you may develop the tab bar in a native environment and load the web app individually in a web view component (e.g. UIWebView for iPhone).