# Horizontal Tabs using jQTouch

Tags: jqtouch

How can we create a horizontal tab menu using jQTouch tab. Here is a reference link for jQTouch : 
http://blog.peepcode.com/tutorials/2009/jqtouch-cheat-sheet

but it does not contain help for tab bar in the top (below toolbar)  or bottom

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be after the tab bar control in jQTouch. Check out this post that might give you the answer you are after: [iPhone - Phonegap UI Controls - Tab Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870067/iphone-phonegap-ui-controls-tab-bar/3911714#3911714).